# Bookmarklet to delete a Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, bookmarklet

I'm looking for a bookmarklet which will delete the current Google Sheet (rather than the `"Move to bin"` menu option). I can see from the JavaScript that the `"File">"Move to bin"`code looks like this:

```
Ih = Ak(uk("docs-trash").label("Move to bin").Ea(765), "trash").dc("bin | delete | remove ||").build();
```

I thought that the solution might be:
   `javascript: document.getElementById("docs-trash").click();`

Am I going down the wrong route trying to do it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope something like this may be helpful to you:

```
javascript:(function() {
    var eltMove = document.querySelector('#\\:b2>div>span');
    fireMouseEvent(document.querySelector('#docs-file-menu'), 'mousedown');
    fireMouseEvent(eltMove, 'mousedown');
    fireMouseEvent(eltMove, 'mouseup');
    fireMouseEvent(eltMove, 'mouseup');

    function fireMouseEvent(eltTarget, myEvent) {
        var screenX, screenY, clientX, clientY;
        var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        event.initMouseEvent(myEvent, true, true, window, 1, screenX, screenY, clientX, clientY, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        eltTarget.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks @Shugar - nifty work. I see I was well off on my thought on how to do it! So first menu is available but second has to be moved to as an macro/mouse movement. Much appreciated.

Comment: Nice to hear :)